# jquery bootstrap dynamic fields with remote calls

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap/jquery to add rows (at runtime) with dynamic fields to the form (apart from the static fields). I went through formvalidation.io to get some idea. The first row is static, but the remaining rows are dynamic. I created a template (but hidden) for the dynamic rows in bootstrap. When user clicks "+" symbol, it makes the hidden template (row) visible.

I am incrementing the host_index from 0 for every row of fields added which is part of name and id attributes of each field in that row. Whenever I add a field in a row, I immediately add the validators for that field. I dynamically create the name and id parameters of each field.

The dynamic fields (from second row) also needed to be validated with a remote call. For some reason, when I tried to get a value of a select box or an input box (which were dynamically created) on the remote call, I do not get any value back. But I get a value back on the static fields. The control does not go to second row for validation at all. Not sure what I am missing.

Can you please help?

Here is the code:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var host_index = 0;
        var val = Math.random();

        $('#host_type')
        // Add button click handler
        .on('click', '.addButton', function() {
            if(host_Index < 10){
                    host_index++;
                    var $template = $('#type_Template'),
                    $clone    = $template
                            .clone()
                            .removeClass('hide')
                            .removeAttr('id')
                            .attr('dns-index', host_index)
                            .insertBefore($template);

                    // Update the name and id attributes
                    $clone
                    .find('[name="cat"]').attr('name', 'host_' + host_index + '_cat').end()
                    .find('[name="cat"]').attr('id', 'host_' + host_ndex + '_cat').end()
                    .find('[name="host"]').attr('name', 'host_' + host_ndex + '_host').end()
                    .find('[name="host"]').attr('id', 'host_' + host_ndex + '_host').end()
                    .find('[name="subnet"]').attr('name', 'host_' + host_ndex + '_subnet').end()
                    .find('[name="subnet"]').attr('id', 'host_' + host_ndex + '_subnet').end();
                   //Not going to this part
                    $clone.find('select[name="host_" + host_index + "_cat"]').rules('add', {
                            required: true
                    });

                    $clone.find('input[name="host_" + host_index + "_host"]').rules('add', {
                            required: true,
                            validate_host: true,
                            remote: {
                                    url: '/host/data.cgi',
                                    type: 'GET',
                                    data: {
                                            'mode': 'validate_host',
                                            'location': function(){
                                                    return $("#location option:selected").text();
                                            },
                                            'category': function(){
                                                    //Not getting any value
                                                    var cat_id=$('select[name=host_'+host_index+'_cat option:selected]');
                                                    return cat_id.text();
                                            },
                                            'hostname': function() {
                                                     //Not getting any value
                                                    var host_id=$('input[name=host_'+host_index+'_host]');       
                                                    return host_id.val();                                     
                                            },                                                                
                                            'subnet': function() {                                            
                                                    return $(subnet_id).val();                                
                                            },                                                                
                                            'val': val                                                        
                                    },                                                                        
                                    dataFilter: function(data, type){                                         
                                            var json = JSON.parse(data);                                      
                                            ...
                    ...                                                                 
                                            return true;                                                    
                                    }                                                                         
                            }                                                                                 
                    });                                                                                       
            }                                                                                                 
    })                                                                                                        

    // Remove button click handler                                                                            
    .on('click', '.removeButton', function() {                                                                
        var $row  = $(this).parents('.form-group'),                                                           
            index = $row.attr('dns-index');                                                                   

        // Remove element containing the fields                                                               
        $row.remove();                                                                                        
    });

       $("#hostForm").validate({  
           //validate the first row and other static fields (with the remote call)
       });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

there is 2 records of

> $clone.find('input[name="host_" + host_index + "_host"]').rules

you need to change it to

```
$clone.find("input[name='host_" + host_index + "_host']").rules
```

the way you ware putting it it will concatenate host_index as a string to rest of the string not the value of host_index.

Comment: Thanks a lot Shouhai for your response. I tried your suggestion, still the field is not getting validated in the remote call. I even tried adding the remote call immediately during changing the name attribute like below: